# How to suppress main thread until a TimerTask thread which is invoked by main thread is finished?

Tags: java, multithreading, timertask

In my main thread I send some data to server via HttpURLConnection, then I start a `timer` to execute a TimerTask periodically to check the response of server. When I get the expected string I call `timer.cancel()`. After this, main thread resume from where the `timer` is started.

I imagine following simplified code with the same mechanism just for this post:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {  
        System.out.println("start");
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        TmTask timerTask = new TmTask(timer);       
        Thread thread = new Thread(timerTask,"thread_1");
        thread.start();
        thread.join();      
        System.out.println("end");
    }  
}

class TmTask extends TimerTask{
    Timer t;

    public TmTask(Timer t){
        this.t = t;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        t.schedule(new A(t), 100, 1000);

    }   
}
class A extends TimerTask{
    private Timer t;
    private int i = 0;
    public A(Timer t) {
        this.t = t;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("abc" );
        i++;
        if (i == 3) t.cancel();
    }   
}
```

My expection is :

```
start
abc
abc
abc
end
```

But I get:

```
start
end
abc
abc
abc
```

Finally I realized that in my code there are 3 threads created but I expected 2 (main thread, and Timer thread), and the `join()` method works on the thread named `thread_1` instead of the timer thread. But I have no idea how to improve it.

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: why do you want to use the thread again? When you are waiting on it in main thread you can just execute it on the main thread...

Comment: This would break the idea of a thread. You want to use threads for asynchronous work. What you want to do is force it back to be synchronous.

Comment: Under no circumstances should a TimerTask contain a reference to a Timer.  The task *is* the background work;  it should not *start* other background work.

Comment: @VGR I get it. Thanks. Just curious, does this mean that there's no way to get the reference of the background task which is started by another background task?

Comment: It’s possible, but it’s a sign of a poor design.  If you really need to wait for background tasks, use an [ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) or [CompletableFuture](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole purpose of creating a new Thread is to start it separately from the main thread - to get parallel execution. You got 3 threads because the timertask creates its own thread. If you want your current (main) thread to stop and wait for result then you can just do something like:

```
boolean result = false;
while( ! result ) {
 result=checkForResult();
 Thread.sleep(1000);
}
```

This will pause the current thread and cause it to block. Usually for such external tasks and async calls you DO NOT want the main thread to stop execution and wait because you don't know when will you get result and it might wait indefinitely. So probably your result is the desired one? :)

Comment: I would just suggest to throw the whole idea with waiting away, and just execute everything on the main thread, or am i thinking wrong?

Comment: Yeah that's what I am trying to say. If you want your main thread to wait you don't need additional threads. The idea for threads is to run something in parallel to the main thread.

Comment: But for blocking tasks running it in parallel and not waiting might be the correct choice - and then what he has done is right and what he wants to do is wrong ;)